# Passing Query Parameters in WordPress URL

Tags: wordpress, url, parameters

I am successfully using the following code in my theme's functions.php file to pass a variable (page number) from a URL (in my case, this is after a mysql query which yields several hundred results):

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "myvar";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

and then the following to use the variable:

```
global $wp_query;
if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['myvar']))
{
$myvar= urldecode($wp_query->query_vars['myvar']);
}
```

As a beginner, my question is: how do I edit each of these blocks of code to create and use multiple variables (e.g., myvar2, myvar3, etc.)? Not only do I need to pass a page number, but I need to pass search parameters from the mysql query which are input by the user via forms). I could experiment (as I just did), but for a beginner, messing around with my theme's function.php file and then having the entire site crash requiring me to edit via file manager is a bit nerve-racking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="?hello=123&bye=456&x=hi"> link </a>
$hello = $_GET['hello'];
$bye = $_GET['bye'];
$x = $_GET['x'];
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Will test tomorrow.

Comment: I don't understand why it works for all of the variables (given the reference to only one variable in functions.php), but it does work. Thanks.

Comment: Breakermind: Thanks for taking the time to clarify and thereby educate me (I hope)!